# Understanding a loop with fscanf

Tags: c++

I've got some code which I'd like to unterstand. My C++ knowledge is a bit rusty, so maybe I could get some pointers (pun intended) to unterstanding the following code excerpt:

```
vector<int> vArray;
FILE * fData;
fData = fopen ("some://path/file.txt", "r");
int iValue;
while(fscanf(fData, "%d", &iValue) != EOF){
 vArray.push_back(iValue);
}
fclose(fData);
```

The two questions which I have are the following:

1. How does the `while` loop with the `fscanf` work exactly? Does it read line-wise, character-wise, or something else?
2. What happens if there are floating point values, such as 0.05, 1.22 or -5.3 in the file? Is there a type conversion?

As I understand it, `vArray` is a vector which will only contain integers, and `vArray.push_back(iValue)` will append the value of `iValue` as a new entry to the vector. What I don't understand is the method of assining a value to `iValue`.

Comment: Why are you using `stdio` in C++?

Comment: He's trying to understand it, he's not using it.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ - that's probably what an answer would contain.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` function return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

Answer (score 1):

**1.How does the while loop with the fscanf work exactly? Does it read line-wise, character-wise, or something else?**

fscanf reads data from the stream and stores them according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.

**2.What happens if there are floating point values, such as 0.05, 1.22 or -5.3 in the file? Is there a type conversion?**

if you want to read float values you should use the %f. i think your loop will read only integers.
for some more info u can see fscanf [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)

Comment: So I understand that `%d` will read single decimals (including a sign, e.g. `-`). What happens with items which are not of the type of the specified parameter, such as commas and decimal points? In my case, is `-5.3, 1.3` going to be treated the same as `-5 3 1 3`?

Comment: @Roland they are different, when you use `%d` to read float value, it it undefined behavior

Comment: I know that if you have for example something like this 5.43  in your file u can read it using this "%d%.2f" in your fscaf. So i guess that if you want to read 5.3 and you are using %d you will get an error but try it just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` family of functions, when used in simple way like question code, will first read and ignore any whitespace, then parse input according to format conversion, until next incompatible character for that format conversion, usually the next whitespace. Spaces and newlines are treated the same way, so input does not need to be line-oriented.

`EOF` constant is defined to be -1, which is what *stdio* functions return on IO error or end-of-file. So the while loop will keep reading until `fscanf` encounters IO error or end of file.

However, this code is seriously bad, because `scanf` family of functions return number of successfully parsed items. If there is non-numeric data in the file, it will fail to parse that 1 integer it's asked to parse in your code. So it returns 0 instead of 1 to indicate nothing was parsed, and it will leave the first invalid character to the stream.

So, if there's invalid data in file `fscanf` returns 0 (`iValue` is unchanged), which is not `EOF`, so loop continues. Next `fscanf` reads the invalid data again, returns 0, and you have infinite loop.

Incidentally, this will happen if there are floating point values with `.` in them, because `.` is invalid char when parsing integer.

The simples fix is to change condition to

```
while(fscanf(fData, "%d", &iValue) == 1){
```

Then loop will exit on both return values `EOF` and `0`, and infinite loop is avoided. In real code, you might want to handle end-of-file and parse error differently, of course.